# Trigger ran with dbo user throws "Server principal is not able to access the database"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

A trigger running on one database with execute as owner is failing to insert to another database when it runs even though the user is the dbo of the both databases.

Error: The server principal "AUser" is not able to access the database "DatabaseB" under the current security context.

Example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "MyTrigger"
ON "DatabaseA".dbo.MyTable
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO DatabaseB.dbo."MyOtherTable" (ColumnA) VALUES ('test');
END
GO
```

"AUser" is DBO of DatabaseA and DatabaseB, updating a record in "DatabaseA".dbo.MyTable now will cause the server principal error

EDIT: Enabling TRUSTWORTHY on DatabaseA fixes this but I'd rather not do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you've used "WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER" clause.

When your DML trigger/stored procedure uses "WITH EXECUTE AS", the principal to impersonate is **user**, not login, you can see it clearly here:

[EXECUTE AS Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql)

[image]

> ' user_name '
>
> Specifies the statements inside the module execute **in
> the context of the user** specified in user_name. Permissions for any
> objects within the module are verified against user_name. user_name
> cannot be specified for DDL triggers with server scope or logon
> triggers. Use login_name instead.

So using execute as user clause you've sandboxed the execution within a database.

When you don't use this clause, a procedure/trigger is executed by login, so if the login is able to access another db it will work. But by executing as a **user** you don't use login anymore, so even if the owner would be **sa** you'd still get the same error:

> The server principal **"sa"** is not able to access the database
> "DatabaseB" under the current security context.

The unsecure way to resolve this issue is to make your `databaseA` `TRUSTWORTHY` + its owner should have `AUTHENTICATE SERVER` permission.

This can be used if you have no `db_owners` of `databaseA` that are not `sysadmins`, otherwise they can elevate their permissions to `sysadmin`.

Other way is more complicated but **secur**e: use of `certificates`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've used execute as because new users can be created on the fly without being given permission to DatabaseB.

Would another solution be to remove the execute as then grant insert to guest or public on DatabaseB? Or would users still need to be mapped to DatabaseB?

Comment: The way you described will work, but by granting CONNECT to guest you open databaseB to **everyone**, it's fine until you don't grant any permission to guest, but you want to grant INSERT to guest or public, by doing this you will permit to **everyone** to insert into a table in databaseB, is it acceptable?

Comment: I figured as much, the bit I'm not clear on is if everyone means every login or literally everyone that can get through the firewall to make a request to the sql server

Comment: I mean every login. Normally, a login, unless it is mapped to a certain database or is a member of sysadmin role, gives the access to server only. When a guest is given CONNECT to a database (you can see it in system databases), a login can access this database (but still has no permissions in it). By granting permissions to guest you grant them to every login on your server that is not mapped explicitely.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm going to grant connect and insert to guest then as I think using trustworthy is a bigger security risk than just granting connect and insert to guest

Comment: You can try to use a certificate. It takes more time to implement but it's 100% secured